# c++ : stop only last call of recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, return

I have a function that a call recursively :

```
void myFunction(int j, int N){
    if(j == N)
        return;
    for(int i = j +1 ; i < N ; ++i){
        myfunction(i);
    }
}
```

My problem is that the `return` will stop the full recursion (from the first calling node), but I would like it to stop only the last node. How is that possible ?

**Edit :** it seems that my question is not understandable for everyone, let's rephrase it : (don't pay attention to the code, it is just an example of a recursive function)

Why does a `return` statement stops the full process of the recursive calls ? I would like it to stop only the last call.

Comment: Where is N coming from?

Comment: *You* control when the recurstion stops, so adjust your termination condition!

Comment: Can you elaborate `will stop the full recursion`? This doesn't make sense: the return will not in fact break out of all your other functions. The recursion is able to continue in the calling function body.

Comment: What exactly is this function supposed to do?

Comment: I don't get where the issue is?

Comment: Actually that is exactly what is happening : the return statement is breaking out all of the other statements

Comment: "don't pay attention to the code" - that appears to be what you have done, because your question itself doesn't make any sense, your statement "return statement stops full process of recursive calls" is untrue.

Comment: Provide full code which can be reproduced but not "example code". Also, it is still unclear what are you want.

Comment: your edit still is wrong: `return` only returns out of the most recent function call, NOT the entire callstack (otherwise functions would not work).

Comment: well it does not in my case. I will provide full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return` only affects the immediate function. If you are `return`ing from a recursive function and all parent calls also end, then it's not `return` that causes that but your terminal condition in each parent call must also have become true.

That is: your functions are terminating because they are all testing for and have all met the same condition.

The following is an example where functions continue:

```
#include <iostream>

std::string padding = "     ";
void f(int i, int d) {
    if (d == 4) // only go 4 deep
        return;
    std::string pfx = padding.substr(0, d);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << pfx << "i:" << i << ", d:" << d << "\n";
        f(0, d + 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    f(0, 0);
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/9ePJEE

My early-out is only applied to certain depths, so even though it is a constant I am testing against, I am testing it against a variable. However the recursion continues even after the first time I reach depth 4. `return` does not terminate recursion or the parents, only the immediate function call.

The example function you gave tests `j == N` where `N` is an external value and therefore essentially constant within the frame of your recursion; when one function sees it reach `N` effectively all of them do, thus when the lowest function sees `N` your entire loop unwinds.

--- EDIT ---

Your latest example, when fixed to actually compile, aborts because of the loop constraint. Again, `return` is not the problem, you just have a maximum value (N) which your loops are *all* working towards simultaneously.

http://ideone.com/SmKAuC

```
| | for (i = 3; i < 3)
| | reached 'N' at this level, returning
| reached 'N' at this level, returning
loop iter with i = 2
| j:2, N:3
| for (i = 3; i < 3)
| reached 'N' at this level, returning
```

In this version of your example code, we never hit the explicit `return` we simply run out of function, and even then, we do an iteration with `i = 2`, so this return does not terminate the entire frame.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the node has any children, and if it doesn't you exit the recursion.

```
void myFunction(int j){
    if(j->next == NULL)
        return;
    for(int i = j +1 ; i < N ; ++i){
        myfunction(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: `j` is an `int`. You can't do `j->next`.

Comment: His code doesn't make sense as written, really. When he said node, I assumed that node meant nodes in a list of some sort.

Comment: I agree it doesn't make sense. It's not answerable until it does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to call your recursion function in a loop like that; more likely, you want to do something with `j + 1`:

```
void myFunction(int j, int N) {
    if (j == N) {
        return;
    }
    std::cout << j << std::endl;
    myFunction(j + 1, N);
}
```

Now, calling `myFunction(0, 10)` will print the numbers `0` through `9` in ascending order.